# How to import multiple svn dump files in to SVN?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svnadmin

i am migrating a large CVS repository to SVN using **Polarion SVNImporter**. Due to  its large size i got multiple dump files for a single repository, say dmp_part1, dmp_part2 etc. 
My requirement is  to load these multiple dump files (which is actually part of a single repo) to svn server and want to create a single project .
Can I use the following ?

```
$ svnadmin load /path/to/repo < dmp_part1, dmp_part2, dmp_part3
```

If I run the command for each dump, will it creates three different repos?

Please help on this.

Comment: No, just load them one at a time in the correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I run the command for each dump, will it creates three different
>   repos?

No. You should run the command multiple times to load the dumps one by one. [SVNBook | Repository data migration using `svnadmin`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnadmin) provides an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
for dump in dmp_part1 dmp_part2 dmp_part3
do
    svnadmin load /path/to/repo < $dump
done
```

You could run a loop to pick each dump and add it to the same repository.

Comment: I want to load these 3 dumps at a time and want to create a single repo. These dumps are part of a single project in CVS.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.